# <compilation debug="XXX in web config, what scenarios does it affect?

Tags: asp.net, web-config

If I've built my application in release mode, and precompiled the aspxs, what does

```
<compilation debug="true" />
```

do in the Web.config?

Do I still need to set this to false for production code?

Under what circumstances does this have any affect?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [this blog post from ScottGu](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/04/11/442448.aspx) which covers the intricacies of the debug switch and includes some discussion of precompiled sites.

Answer (score 2):

Of course ! If you don't need to debug, don't deploy application with `<compilation debug="true" />`.

It affect ASP.NET resources (aspx, global.asax...) compilation mode and how the Framework will generate Temporary ASP.NET Files for your application.

Briefly, when **debug** is set to **true**, the Framework will compile **each page into a separate assembly** - Plus the compilation symbol etc...
It also mean one assembly access for each page, and performance behaviors...

When **debug** is **false**, all **pages will be compiled into one DLL** (batch compilation).

**EDIT**: Damned, didn't realized you precompiled, sorry for the mistake.

In this case, it depend on your precompilation mode : *deployment only* or *deployment and update*.

But about your ASPX files, debug will have no effects.

***deployment only*** : All files will be precompiled and debug will have no effects on them.

***deployment and update*** : .asmx, .ashx, App_Themes, App_LocalResources will be "as is" and compiled on first access. Note that aspx can be updated in this mode.

Comment: what if ive precompiled the pages though, this was my question

Answer (score 0):

You might have to, you might not.

If the server has  in its machine.config then it forces all websites to run with debug = false.

Otherwise yes you need to disable it when you are launched. It will use less memory when you do.